# R data.table error when joining a data.table to json object

Tags: r, json, mongodb, join, data.table

I am updating records in a MongoDb database via R and some of the fields to update are in a complicated nested list format.  Since I wasn´t able to replicate the structure from scratch, I import the data from the database, keep it in json format as an object in my r environment, create a copy that I convert to data.table and edit that.  I am then using a for loop to update the relevant fields in the json with values from the updated data.table and push them back into MongoDb using `httr:PUT()` and the relevant API.

I found however that if I try to join the values from the data.table directly to the json, I get this error:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(lab_updates, fq) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), the columns to join by must be specified using 'on=' argument (see ?data.table), by keying x (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted, see ?setkey), or by sharing column names between x and i (i.e., a natural join). Keyed joins might have further speed benefits on very large data due to x being sorted in RAM.
```

It seems strange as the other object I am joining to is not a data.table but a json object - should this not be a warning rather than an error?  Or is there a mistake in the syntax in the for loop?  If I convert the data.table to a data.frame, the for loop works fine.

Here is part of the example json (with fake data) I am trying to edit (the full one is too long, but this will give an idea of the structure - the nested questions are listed under `questionnaireAnswers`:

```
> dput(lab_content)
list(list(personId = "0ce29018-1188-42bf-bd2e-2c39688a4c97", 
    personType = "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_PERSON_TYPE_CASE", 
    dateSampleTaken = "2021-08-16T00:00:00.000Z", dateSampleDelivered = "2021-08-19T00:00:00.000Z", 
    dateTesting = "2021-08-19T00:00:00.000Z", dateOfResult = "2021-08-19T00:00:00.000Z", 
    labName = "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_NAME_MOL", sampleIdentifier = "S130_rougeole", 
    sampleType = "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_SAMPLE_SERUM", 
    testType = "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_LAB_TEST_ELISA_ANTICORPS", 
    result = "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_NEGATIVE", 
    quantitativeResult = "0.051", notes = "Exemplaire", status = "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_STATUS_COMPLETED", 
    outbreakId = "732b8a56-84e7-4a77-87cd-103271070c6d", testedFor = "Rougeole", 
    createdAt = "2021-08-19T15:13:07.755Z", createdBy = "65339990-d363-4939-8952-f881c8324b1c", 
    updatedAt = "2021-08-19T15:14:04.544Z", updatedBy = "65339990-d363-4939-8952-f881c8324b1c", 
    createdOn = "API", deleted = FALSE, questionnaireAnswers = list(
        nom_laborantin = list(list(value = "Charles")), 
        molecule = list(list(value = "IgM NP")), unites = list(
            list(value = "ratio DO")), puit = list(list(value = "C06")), 
        resultats_brutes = list(list(value = 0.019)), CQ = list(
            list(value = "reussi")))
))
```

Here is the data.table with the (again dummy data) values to update with:

```
> dput(lab_updates)
setDT(structure(list(personId = c("cef0e9b5-3935-4e4e-9b4e-b40711add5e4", 
"a5ddca7d-4fc9-4569-bc47-c97604740adf", "bcef99af-7305-49db-a292-2ca6a4d0386a"
), id = c("31c9e07a-8330-4798-b902-188c97f38204", "3dc68501-96ca-413d-b096-8b6663f64b6f", 
"69bc7320-35ac-40cb-b45e-2ca4c685e140"), outbreakId = c("732b8a56-84e7-4a77-87cd-103271070c6d", 
"732b8a56-84e7-4a77-87cd-103271070c6d", "732b8a56-84e7-4a77-87cd-103271070c6d"
), sampleIdentifier = c("S131_rougeole", "S132_rougeole", "S133_rougeole"
), labName = c("LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_NAME_MOL", "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_NAME_MOL", 
"LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_NAME_MOL"), sampleType = c("LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_SAMPLE_SERUM", 
"LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_SAMPLE_SERUM", "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_SAMPLE_SERUM"
), testType = c("LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_LAB_TEST_ELISA_ANTICORPS", 
"LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_LAB_TEST_ELISA_ANTICORPS", 
"LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_TYPE_OF_LAB_TEST_ELISA_ANTICORPS"
), testedFor = c("Rougeole", "Rougeole", "Rougeole"), dateSampleTaken = c("2021-08-17T00:00:00.000Z", 
"2021-08-17T00:00:00.000Z", "2021-06-25T00:00:00.000Z"), dateSampleDelivered = c(NA, 
NA, "2021-06-26T00:00:00.000Z"), dateTesting = c("2021-08-19T14:38:00.000z", 
"2021-08-19T14:38:00.000z", "2021-08-19T14:38:00.000z"), dateOfResult = c("2021-08-19T14:38:00.000z", 
"2021-08-19T14:38:00.000z", "2021-08-19T14:38:00.000z"), quantitativeResult = c("0.652883569", 
"0.91", "2.935799782"), result = c("LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_NEGATIVE", 
"LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_INCONCLUSIVE", "LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_POSITIVE"
), status = c("LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_STATUS_COMPLETED", 
"LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_STATUS_COMPLETED", 
"LNG_REFERENCE_DATA_CATEGORY_LAB_TEST_RESULT_STATUS_COMPLETED"
), nom_laborantin = c("Amy", "Amy", "Amy"
), molecule = c("IgM NP", "IgM NP", "IgM NP"), unites = c("ratio DO", 
"ratio DO", "ratio DO"), puit = c("F01", "G01", "H01"), resultats_brutes = c("0.3", 
"0.85", "1.349"), CQ = c("reussi", "reussi", "reussi")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))
```

And here is the for loop that should update the json and push it back to the MongoDB:

```
# Define which fields are in sub-nested format:
questionnaireFields <- c("nom_laborantin", 
                         "molecule", 
                         "unites", 
                         "puit", 
                         "resultats_brutes", 
                         "CQ")

# Define which fields are not sub-nested:
coreFields <- ("personId", "id", "outbreakId", 
               "sampleIdentifier", "labName", 
               "sampleType", "testType", 
               "testedFor", "dateSampleTaken", 
               "dateSampleDelivered", "dateTesting", 
               "dateOfResult", "quantitativeResult", 
               "result") 

# Loop through each lab record ID to push the modifications:
for (i in 1:nrow(lab_updates)) {
    
  # Get lab record IDs:
  lab_id_i <- lab_updates$id[i]
  
  # Get case IDs to update:
  person_id_i <- lab_updates$personId[i]
    
  # Get current snapshot of Go.Data for each lab record:
  for (x in 1:length(lab_content)) {
    
    if (lab_content[[x]]$id == lab_id_i) {
      
      # Get current lab data
      lab_content_i <- lab_content[[x]]
      
      # Create new data packet for the case
      new_content_i <- lab_content_i
      
      # Add new values to the new data packet
      # Do this column by column
      for (fq in questionnaireFields) {
        new_content_i$questionnaireAnswers[fq][[1]][[1]]$value <- lab_updates[fq][[1]][i]
      }
      for (fc in coreFields) {
        new_content_i[fc][[1]] <- lab_updates[fc][[1]][i]
      }
      
      # PUT data into Go.Data:
      put_request <- PUT(paste0(url,
                                "api/outbreaks/",
                                outbreak,
                                "/cases/",
                                person_id_i,
                                "/lab-results/", 
                                lab_id_i),
                         add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", get_token()$token, sep = " ")),
                         body = new_content_i,
                         encode = "json")
      
      warn_for_status(put_request)
      
      rm(lab_content_i, new_content_i, put_request)
    }
  }
  
}
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_Central African Republic.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_Central African Republic.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_Central African Republic.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                                    
[5] LC_TIME=French_Central African Republic.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] jsonlite_1.7.2    httr_1.4.2        forcats_0.5.1     stringr_1.4.0     dplyr_1.0.7       purrr_0.3.4      
 [7] readr_1.4.0       tidyr_1.1.3       tibble_3.1.2      ggplot2_3.3.5     tidyverse_1.3.1   lubridate_1.7.10 
[13] data.table_1.14.0 getPass_0.2-2     here_1.0.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.6.1     compiler_4.1.0   dbplyr_2.1.1     tools_4.1.0      lifecycle_1.0.0 
 [8] gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.11     reprex_2.0.0     cli_2.5.0        rstudioapi_0.13  DBI_1.1.1       
[15] curl_4.3.2       haven_2.4.1      xfun_0.24        xml2_1.3.2       withr_2.4.2      fs_1.5.0         hms_1.1.0       
[22] generics_0.1.0   vctrs_0.3.8      rprojroot_2.0.2  grid_4.1.0       tidyselect_1.1.1 glue_1.4.2       R6_2.5.0        
[29] fansi_0.5.0      readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.8     magrittr_2.0.1   backports_1.2.1  scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.2  
[36] rvest_1.0.0      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-2 utf8_1.2.1       tinytex_0.32     stringi_1.6.2    munsell_0.5.0   
[43] broom_0.7.8      crayon_1.4.1
```

Comment: Why don't you convert the JSON to a `data.table` object using the casting function from the data.table package?

Comment: On which line are you encountering your error?

Comment: @anymous.asker my data needs to be in json format to go back into the MongoDB database - unless I´ve misunderstood, converting from json to data.table wouldn´t help me, it is the opposite that I need to do.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor it is the line starting with the for loop: `for (fq in questionnaireFields)`